# Может ли мое решение задачи отличаться от эталонного?

Tags: java

Условие задачи. Создать новый массив размера 100 и заполнить его случайными числами из диапазона от 0 до 10000. Найти максимум среди сумм трех соседних элементов. Для найденной тройки с максимальной суммой выведите значение суммы и индекс первого элемента тройки.

Пример:

*Для простоты пример показан на массиве размера 10*

```
[1, 456, 1025, 65, 954, 2789, 4, 8742, 1040, 3254]
```

Тройка с максимальной суммой: `[2789, 4, 8742]`

Вывод в консоль:

```
 11535
 5
```

*Пояснение: Первое число — сумма тройки `[2789, 4, 8742]`. Второе число — индекс первого элемента тройки, то есть индекс числа 2789.*

Я решил вот таким образом:

```
public class task4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[100];
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            array[i] = random.nextInt(10000);

        int maxSum = 0;
        int maxSumIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 2; i++) {
            int sum = 0;
            sum = array[i] + array[i + 1] + array[i + 2];
            if (sum > maxSum) {
                maxSum = sum;
                maxSumIndex = i;
            }
            System.out.println(maxSum);
            System.out.println(maxSumIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Правильный ответ выглядит так:

```
public class task4 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] array = new int[100];
            Random random = new Random();
    
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                array[i] = random.nextInt(10000);
    
            int maxSum = 0;
            int maxSumIdx = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 2; i++) {
                int sum = 0;
                for(int j = i; j < i + 3; j++){
                sum += array[j];
                }

                if (sum > maxSum) {
                    maxSum = sum;
                    maxSumIdx = i;
                }
                System.out.println(maxSum);
                System.out.println(maxSumIdx);
            }
        }
    }
```

Уже посмотрев правильный ответ, я для проверки уменьшил массив до 10, вывел все цифры в нем и перепроверил с калькулятором. Вроде все правильно выходит.

Получается, что верны оба решения? Или я все-таки что-то упустил?

Comment: Оба неправильные.

Comment: Как ни странно, одно и то же можно записать множеством разных на вид способов.

Comment: @Igor ну и зачем вы троллите?

Comment: По условию требуется вывести **одну** тройку с максимальной суммой.

Comment: @MBo вот нормальный комментарий, с пояснением. Уверен, что он для ТС куда полезнее.

Comment: @Kromster нет там никакого троллинга. Если код выдает неправильный результат, то как он может быть верным решением?

Comment: @Эникейщик троллинг заключается в том, что "вы все неправильно делаете, но я вам не скажу что именно и не скажу как правильно" - это не конструктивная позиция.

Comment: Почему в примере к задаче неправильный ответ?) Ответ был бы 13036 7, а не 11535 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решения идентичны, просто в первом случае сумма считается в одну строку, а во втором с помощью цикла. В данной задаче разницы нет, но во втором случае, если условие поменяется с "3 чисел" до "4 чисел", то достаточно будет изменить только две переменных, а не дописывать в строку новые слагаемые. Если в алгоритме есть повторение - старайтесь всегда использовать циклы.

```
public class task4 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] array = new int[100];
            Random random = new Random();
    
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                array[i] = random.nextInt(10000);
    
            int maxSum = 0;
            int maxSumIndex = 0;
            int sequenceLen = 3
            for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - sequenceLen; i++) {
                int sum = 0;
                for(int j = i; j < i + sequenceLen; j++){
                    sum += array[j];
                }

                if (sum > maxSum) {
                    maxSum = sum;
                    maxSumIdx = i;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(maxSum);
            System.out.println(maxSumIdx);
        }
    }
```

Еще прочитайте про [Замена магического числа символьной константой](https://refactoring.guru/ru/replace-magic-number-with-symbolic-constant)

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Пока завис на сайте рефракторинга )